Reciprocal Fibonacci constant, metallic ratios, and theta functions
I. Constants
Given the Fibonacci, Lucas, Pell, and companion Pell numbers starting with $n=0$,
$$F(n)=0,1,1,2,3,5,8,\dots\\
L(n)=2,1,3,4,7,11,18\dots\\
P(n)=0,1,2,5,12,29,70\dots\\
Q(n)=2,2,6,14,34,82,198\dots
$$
such that they obey the Pell-like equations,
$$L(n)^2-5F(n)^2 = 4(-1)^n\\
Q(n)^2-8P(n)^2 = 4(-1)^n$$
We skip index $n=0$. Then the reciprocal Fibonacci and reciprocal Lucas constants are,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{F(n)} = 3.35988566\dots\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{L(n)} = 1.96285817\dots$$
which have closed-forms in terms of the golden ratio $\phi=r_1=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and other functions. But it seems we can generalize those closed-forms to the Pell and companion Pell numbers using the silver ratio $r_2=\frac{2+\sqrt8}2 = 1+\sqrt2$, and similar sequences using other metallic ratios.

II. Sequences
Let the $m$th metallic ratio $r_m$ be,
$$r_m = \frac{m+\sqrt{m^2+4}}2$$
Define its two associated integer sequences,
$$S_m(n)=\frac{r_m^n-(-r_m)^{-n}}{\sqrt{m^2+4}}$$
$$T_m(n)=r_m^n+(-r_m)^{-n}$$
which for $m=1$ just yields the Fibonacci and Lucas sequences, while $m=2$ yields the Pell sequence and its companion.

III. Formulas
Let $d=m^2+4$ and $r=r_m$ for brevity. Given the Lambert series $L(z)$ and Jacobi theta functions $\vartheta_k(0,q)$. Then,
I. Reciprocal sequence constant of the 1st kind
\begin{align}\alpha_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{S_m(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{S_m(2n-1)}+\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{S_m(2n)}}\\ 
&=\frac{\sqrt{d}}4\Big(\vartheta_2\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2 + \color{blue}{\sqrt{d}\;\Big(L\big(r^{-2}\big)-L\big(r^{-4}\big)\Big)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{d}}4\Big(\vartheta_2\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2+ \sqrt{d}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{r^{2n}-1}-\frac1{r^{4n}-1}\right)
\end{align}
II. Reciprocal sequence constant of the 2nd kind
\begin{align}\quad\beta_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{T_m(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{T_m(2n-1)}+\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{T_m(2n)}}\\
&=\, L\big(r^{-1}\big)-2L\big(r^{-2}\big)+L\big(r^{-4}\big)\,+\,\color{blue}{\frac14\Big(\vartheta_3\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2-\frac14}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac1{r^{n}-1}-\frac2{r^{2n}-1}+\frac1{r^{4n}-1}\Big)+\frac14\Big(\vartheta_3\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2-\frac14\\
\end{align}
The blue part shows a nice feature of these formulas: they can be separated into odd and even indices. Thus, the alternating series,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\,(-1)^{n-1}}{S_m(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{S_m(2n-1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{S_m(2n)}$$
also has a closed-form as in this post. So the reciprocal Fibonacci and Lucas constants are just $(\alpha_1,\,\beta_1)$ being the first case $m=1$ with $r_1=\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$. The reciprocal Pell and companion constants $(\alpha_2,\,\beta_2)$ are then the second case $m=2$ with $r_2=\frac{2+\sqrt8}2 = 1+\sqrt2$,
$$\alpha_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{P(n)} = 1.842203049\dots\\
\beta_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{Q(n)} = 0.788323975\dots\\$$
and so on for other $m$. The decimal expansion of $(\alpha_1,\,\beta_1)$ are in the OEIS as A079586 and A093540, but not yet for $(\alpha_2,\,\beta_2)$.

III. Question
The formulas were extrapolated from the $(\alpha_1,\,\beta_1)$. But how to prove that with the metallic ratio $r = r_m$ and integer sequences $S_m(n)$ and $T_m(n)$ as defined in Section II, then,
\begin{align}
\alpha_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{S_m(n)} \overset{\color{red}?}= \sqrt{d}\;\Big(L\big(r^{-2}\big)-L\big(r^{-4}\big)\Big) + \frac{\sqrt{d}}4\Big(\vartheta_2\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2\\
\beta_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{T_m(n)} \overset{\color{red}?}=
L\big(r^{-1}\big)-2L\big(r^{-2}\big)+L\big(r^{-4}\big)+\frac14\Big(\vartheta_3\big(0,r^{-2}\big)\Big)^2-\frac14
\end{align}
for all positive integer $m$?

Checking similar posts, it seems there is a use for the even part (in blue) of $\alpha$, for the Fibonacci case. And I forgot I asked a similar question also for the even part of $\beta$ and was answered by Sangchul Lee.
